# JavaScript for loop being skipped with no errors

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coding-style

I have here a block of JC code:
$

```
 function Test() {
        var form = $('form').serializeArray();
        var str = "";
        var Price = {};
        var OneUp = 1;
        var NextName = "";
        var PriceIndex = 0
    for (var i = 0, l = form.length; i < l; i++) {
        OneUp = i + 1;
        if (form[i].name.indexOf("_Sel_") != -1) {
            NextName = form[OneUp].name.substring(0, form[OneUp].name.indexOf(":"));
            Price[PriceIndex] = form[OneUp].name.substring(form[OneUp].name.indexOf(":") + 1, form[OneUp].name.length);
            PriceIndex += 1;
            str += form[i].name.replace("_Sel_", "") + ':   <span class="ColorMe">' + NextName + "</span><br/>";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = Price.length; i < l; i++) {
        Price[i] = parseFloat(Price[i]) + .05;
    }
    var Total = 0.05;
    for (var i = 0, l = Price.length; i < l; i++) {
        Total += Price[i];
    }
    $(".PriceMe").html(Total.toString());
    $(".UpdateMe").html(str);

};
```

For no apparent reason or any errors this section of the code is being skipped:

```
for (var i = 0, l = Price.length; i < l; i++) {
    Price[i] = parseFloat(Price[i]) + .05;
}
var Total = 0.05;
for (var i = 0, l = Price.length; i < l; i++) {
    Total += Price[i];
}
$(".PriceMe").html(Total.toString());
```

Can anyone please explain to me why and or a fix to my current problem.
Also i do apologize I am a novice JC coder, so any style or other issues you see in my code will be gladly accepted.
Thxs.

Comment: Price.length is undefined at that point...

Comment: Thxs everyone your answers were dead on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Price** is an object (`{}`) so it does not have the **length** property
to go through object you need to do this for example:

```
var obj = {};
obj['key'] = 'value';
obj['key2'] = 'value2';
for(var val in obj){
   //val => key
   //obj[val] => value
}
```

Comment: Worked like i charm, Thanks.
I dont however understand how form has the .length property but Price does not.

Comment: cause serializeArray return an array: [http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)  happy to get the mark - thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

`Price.length` is undefined at that point so use this :

```
  for (var i = 0, l = $(Price).length; i < l; i++) {
        Price[i] = parseFloat(Price[i]) + .05;
    }
    var Total = 0.05;
    for (var i = 0, l = Price.length; i < l; i++) {
        Total += Price[i];
    }
    $(".PriceMe").html(Total.toString());
```

and for access obj values you can use `for(var key in obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon after `var PriceIndex = 0`. There is no need to declare hundred variables in the for loop. You can just simply use for `(var i = 0; i < Price.length; i++)`.

If you declare multiple variables after each other you can do this like this:

```
var a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
```

You don't need to use `var` the whole time. The `length` method is only for arrays or html element collections. In order to get properties from an object you loop that object with an `in` keyword like this `for (i in object)` To access object you either use `object.property` or `object["property"]` if you do it like so `object[property]`, javascript will think property is an variable, and is going to search for it and if it finds it javascript will return the value and start searching for in that object if the value will be other than a string, or the value will be not found in that object, javascript will return value `undefined`.

Edit:

form has a length property because jQuery searches DOM for that element, and it returns a html elements collection, which like an array has the length property.